# TypeScript/Knex: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, knex.js

I'm a newbie to TypeScript and currently using Knex to build a template table in our PostgreSQL database. On this file and others and am continually running in to this same issue with TypeScript, code is as follows:

```
import * as Knex from 'knex';


exports.up = async (knex: Knex): Promise<void> => {
    await knex.schema.raw(`
    CREATE TABLE test (
        test TEXT NOT NULL,
        tes2  INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (key, website)
    ) 
`);
}


exports.down = async (knex: Knex): Promise<void> => {
    await knex.schema.dropTable('test');
}
```

and I get this error:

```
import * as Knex from 'knex';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I have also tried these varients:

```
   import * as Knex = require('knex');
   import { * as Knex } from 'knex';
   const * = require('knex');
   const { * as Knex } = require('knex');
```

But I cannot find any solution online which seems to solve the problem.

Any help on this would be awesome.

Answer (score 13):

Tried alot of things and nothing helped, trying to change the type to module only made things worse.
After all what was missing was ts-node:

yarn add ts-node -D

And you're done =]

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing two different kinds of modules. `import`/`export` is [JavaScript standard module syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) ("ESM" for "ECMAScript Module"), but assigning to properties on `exports` is [CommonJS module syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (aka "CJS"). You need to use one or the other, and if you're using ESM, you need to tell Node.js that by using `"type": "module"` in `package.json` or using the `.mjs` file extension — or, since you're using TypeScript, you might want `"module": "ES2020"` or similar ([more here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module)).

The error tells us that Node.js and/or TypeScript think you're using CJS. If you want to keep doing that, it would probably be:

```
const Knex = require("knex");
```

...but [see the documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-node), as they show calling that export as a function. (Perhaps you're doing that later.)

Comment: Ok awesome, another basic question and I should have specified this point originally.. The file I have posted about is a .ts file. Should this file instead be .js/.mjs for it to ideally work? Meanwhile I'll get on this. Thanks for such a quick response.

Comment: @Maximoose - Sorry, you did say you were using TypeScript and I forgot to address that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I use node with Typescript, but don't use the module mode.  Typescript is great for this feature, as I do like the ESM imports etc, but nodes implementation causes too many compromises.

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur if you setup knex **without** specifying you'll be using typescript.

Make sure you use the following command to initialize knex, if you're creating typescript migrations:

```
knex init -x ts
```

Answer (score 0):

1. At first make sure you've instantiate a typescript project so you may need to add typescript to your dependencies

   yarn add -D typescript
2. Make sure to also have a tsconfig.json file
3. Add a knexfile.ts to your project root dir with this command

   knex init -x ts